# Изменение данных в access ado net

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, ms-access

Сразу скажу я только учусь.

Есть таблица Access которая выводится в datagrid в wpf.
Я пытаюсь изменить данные в wpf чтобы они записывали в таблицу access но выходит ошибка.
Делал по аналогии с localdb
Код ниже

```
 var accessUpdate = $@"UPDATE ORDERS SET 
                       email = @emailAccess,
                       product_number = @product_number, 
                       product_name = @product_name
                       WHERE Id = @idAccess";

            daAccess.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(accessUpdate, accessConnection);
            daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@emailAccess", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "email");
            daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_number", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_number");
            daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_name", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_name");
```

wpf

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="gridViewAccess" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                          CurrentCellChanged="ChangedAccess" 
                          CellEditEnding="ChangedEndingAccess" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idAccess" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Id}" 
                                    Header="Id" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailAccess" 
                                    Binding="{Binding email}" 
                                    Header="email"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="product_number" 
                                    Binding="{Binding product_number}" 
                                    Header="Код товара"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="product_name" 
                                    Binding="{Binding product_name}" 
                                    Header="Наименование товара"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Ну и соответсвенно ChangedAccess и ChangedEndingAccess

```
private void ChangedAccess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            if (drAccess == null) return;
            drAccess.EndEdit();
            daAccess.Update(dtAccess);
    }


    private void ChangedEndingAccess(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        drAccess = (DataRowView)gridViewAccess.SelectedItem;
        drAccess.BeginEdit();
    }


    DataTable dtAccess;
    OleDbDataAdapter daAccess;
    DataRowView drAccess;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я предполагаю, что он не может понять что такое idAccess(это имя поля в wpf), потому что если удалить это поле, то значения меняются но сразу для всей таблицы. Подскажи пожалуйста как исправить) Если можно простыми словами)

Comment: В sql-запросе указаны четыре параметра, а в UpdateCommand вы добавляете только три.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я если добавляю что то вроде daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@idAccess", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Id"); Появляется ошибка  "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: ну наверно потому что "Id" - это не число, а вы пишете, что оно OleDbType.Integer?

Comment: @tym32167 https://prnt.sc/acOi0wO91D4G число оно у меня в таблице. Не открывается фото. Вообщем если зайти в свойства Id  в таблице там будет тип данных OleDbType.Integer точность 10